# Android Webview doen't work correctly

Tags: android, android-webview

This site works well in android browsers but it doesn't work in android webview.
I set internet permission and did all things.
Who can teach me?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView web_view;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        OneSignal.startInit(this).init();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        web_view = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        web_view.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
        web_view.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        web_view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web_view.setWebViewClient(mWebViewClient);
        web_view.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(), "android");
        web_view.loadUrl("http://182.72.55.182/pms/employee");
    }
    WebViewClient mWebViewClient = new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl("javascript:window.android.onUrlChange(window.location.href);");
        };
    };

    class MyJavaScriptInterface {
        @JavascriptInterface
        public void onUrlChange(String url) {
            Log.d("hydrated", "onUrlChange" + url);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

make sure that your regarding website becoming live in everywhere!
webview doesn't display any local host website

Answer (score 0):

Try to put `WebViewClient` part inside the `onCreate`.